# What is the role of 「より」 and 「かつ」 in this sentence

Tags: grammar, words

Below is a paragraph from a Japanese light novel. (Classroom of the Elite - Volume I)

> そして、その教えは少なくとも２０１５年を迎えた現代においても何一つ事実として変わっていない。もっとも、事態は**より**複雑**かつ**[深刻化]{しんこくか}しているが。

What exactly 「より」and 「かつ」do in the second sentence?

Also, what kind of meaning does 「が」 at the very end add to the sentence/pragraph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> もっとも、事態はより複雑かつ深刻化しているが。
>   Well, the situation has become *more* complicated *and* serious, *though*.

- より right before an adjective is "more". See: [Different versions of より?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5556/5010)
- かつ is a stiff way of saying "and". It's 且つ in kanji, although this kanji is rarely used. 複雑かつ深刻化している is "複雑化している and 深刻化している" ([right-node raising](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17744/5010)).
- Sentence-end が (or けど, けれど, けれども) is "..., though." It makes a contrast with what has already been mentioned in the previous sentence.
- Just in case you didn't know, this もっとも is not 最も but 尤も, which is like "that being said" or "although". See: [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: もっとも](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82-motto-mo/)